# linux: how to run a command in a given directory

Tags: linux, cron

I simply want to just run a command (actually its a shell script) from a given directory as a cron job. How can I run it so that it is set to a given directory without using `cd`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your question makes little sense. Use `cd`. If you ask for the answer not to use `cd` because you've tried it and it didn't work, it's likely you didn't enter it correctly in the crontab.

The simplest way would be to write a small shell script that will cd and run your main task, then cron the script.

Comment: Can crontab let me put multiple commands inside one job? If not I would have to **harcode** the cd [path]. And path might change, thus causing really annoying deployment issues and also decentralizing configuration which is something I am avoiding at all costs.

Comment: @Zombies: yes, you can put multiple commands inside one job (e.g. separating them with semicolons or `&&`), but you can also write a separate script that contains all the commands and just put the path to the script in cron, like Daenyth suggested. Your script could do something like reading the directory from a configuration file if you like - the point is, however you want to get the directory name into your script, it's no excuse not to use `cd`.

Comment: I see. I will want to use cd on the crontab directly since if I write it in a file, I will have to edit it in each file which makes for delicate/easy-to-break configurations.

Comment: And if you put the cd in the crontab file, you will have to edit it in each crontab file. I don't understand the problem. Maybe you could explain what you're trying to do more fully.

Comment: And the other reason for running a shell script from the crontab file is to ensure that the environment is set correctly.  The environment given to a cron job is normally barely even minimal, so you usually need to reset it to something more usable.

Comment: If you're worried about updating across scripts, make a bash config file that defines the directory and have all scripts source it.

Answer (score 72):

Just specify the path to the script. No need for `cd`:

```
0 12 * * * /path/to/script args
```

If your script looks for files in `.`, then you *will* have to use `cd`:

```
0 12 * * * cd /some/dir && /path/to/script args
```

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/290313/how-to-change-directory-in-cron-for-doxygen-code-documentation

Comment: `&&`, as in the answer @WillSheppard links to, would be better than `;` because `&&` only runs the next command if the previous command was successful.