# cron and flock with change directory command

Tags: linux, cron

I have the following cronjob specified and it is working as intended, except that sometimes it runs duplicate jobs which should not happen. I.e. the first one would have to be terminated first.

Command is as follows:

```
10 * * * * cd /home/info/ && /home/info/file -a 10 -b "randomstring" >> /home/log.txt 2>&1
```

As you can see I have included 'cd' command because the script needs to read certain file; see here (https://superuser.com/a/155634). Now, to resolve the duplicated jobs issue, I decided to add flock, unfortunately it does not seem to accept the above command as acceptable.

Command is as follows:

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/flock -xn /tmp/ms.lockfile 'cd /home/info/ && /home/info/file -a 10 -b "randomstring"' >> /home/log.txt 2>&1
```

Error:

**flock: failed to execute cd /home/info/ && /home/info/file -a 10 -b "randomstring": No such file or directory**

Could someone tell me if I am doing something wrong with the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man 1 flock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html):

> ```
> flock [options] file|directory command [arguments]
> flock [options] file|directory -c command
> ```

In the first form `command` should be a single executable. Arguments to it should be provided as separate arguments to `flock`.

You're using the first form and your (single-quoted) `cd /home/info/ && /home/info/file -a 10 -b "randomstring"` becomes the `command`. There is no such command.

In addition you're using `cd` and `&&`. This means you cannot just drop the single-quotes. You need a shell to interpret `&&` and make `cd` work as intended. Use the second form, according to the following:

> `-c`, `--command command`
>   Pass a single `command`, without arguments, to the shell with `-c`.

Simply add `-c` just before `'cd … && …'`. The line will become:

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/flock -xn /tmp/ms.lockfile -c 'cd /home/info/ && /home/info/file -a 10 -b "randomstring"' >> /home/log.txt 2>&1
```

---

Note you can use the first form to explicitly specify a shell (e.g. `zsh`):

```
flock -xn /tmp/ms.lockfile /bin/zsh -c 'cd … && …'
```

Here `-c` is not the one that distinguishes the second form. The line uses the first form: `/bin/zsh` is the `command` and `-c` is a part of `arguments`. The equivalentish second form is

```
flock -xn /tmp/ms.lockfile -c 'cd … && …'
```

but it may use a different shell. In my Debian 9 the value of the `SHELL` environment variable is relevant. Knowing this, we can build the equivalent (not just equivalentish) second form:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh flock -xn /tmp/ms.lockfile -c 'cd … && …'
```

Comment: AHH, there is different syntax. Flock be like; 'this isn't even my final form!' haha. Nice thanks that works. I have this if anyone is interested: 10 * * * * /usr/bin/flock -xn /tmp/ms.lockfile -c 'cd /home/info/ && /home/info/file -a 10 -b "randomstring" >> /home/log.txt 2>&1'